# Doing math with formatting characters

Tags: python, formatting, character

I'm quite new to programming and just started learning some python.
I've come across a problem that I can't find a solution for. Hope you can help.

```
height = 74.0 # inches

cm = 2.54 # inches

print "He's %f * %f centimeters tall." % (height, cm)
```

So the problem is I want the console to output the result and **not** `"%f * %f"` and doing so without slicing the string multiple times. Any solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with `print("He's %f centimeters tall." % (height * cm) )`?

Comment: han use `print "He's %f centimeters tall." % (height * cm,)

Comment: Thanks for your help. The solution was much easier than what I thought it would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what your'e asking
But `print "He's %f centimeters tall." % (height * cm)`
Will print one number and it will be `height` multiplied by `cm`

Comment: Ah, thanks! That did the trick. Think the solution was much easier than first expected.

Comment: I am happy to help:)

Answer (score 0):

I would believe the solution is something like this:
 print("He's %f centimeters tall." % (height * cm)